# Laravel file web editor

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I work at a place where software installations and internet is heavily monitored, and they won't allow FTP or SSH connections. I'm also working on a Laravel project that is due very soon, and I would like to use some of the free time at work to write a line or two to help expedite the finish date. My question is: is there a web file editor that would allow me to edit my Laravel dist files from the browser and run commands like `php artisan`?

if NOT, I thought of using php's `scandir` and `shell_exec` to accomplish the task, but I always get `routeNotFoundException`. Any Ideas? Thank you all

Comment: I would suggest you use your own phone hotspot, but I have a feeling that you want to make others work at your work, you might be clear with that with your employer

Comment: If I use my phone's hotspot, I would lose access to the intranet and ERP etc....

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully managed to create a little web editor using `php`. The trick is to move the files outside of the Laravel dist. All commands used are pretty simple such as `chdir()` and `shell_exec`.